# Broken files in User Extended Fields Plugin for K2 and Joomla

Tags: css, plugins, joomla, custom-fields

I am having a problem getting the User Extended Fields Plugin (http://getk2.org/extend/extensions/73-user-extended-fields-for-k2) to work properly with my website. I currently am running Joomla! 3.2 and K2 2.6.8. Anyways, I have two problems:

Big problem: In my admin side, when editing a user, the bottom under the standard user fields is just has a clump of fields with no CSS whatsoever, despite the correct CSS being loaded properly to the document.

Smaller yet still important problem: Also, when editing this plugin, none of the language files are being translated. I have language files in the correct places, yet I still have the problem.

Please help.

Comment: Have you contacted the K2 developers?

Comment: I posted in the community forum they have but have not been able to get too much help, the developers don't want to be asked about questions like this